# What version of TinyMCE will work in Drupal 5 with google chrome?

Tags: drupal, tinymce, drupal-5

My drupal site (internal) will not display the TinyMCE editor when using Google Chrome browser. Has anyone gotten TinyMCE to work with Chrome in Drupal 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Refresh the edit page and the editor will render in Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of known incompatibilities between TinyMCE and WebKit (the rendering engine used by Chrome).  If you're using TinyMCE 2.x, you might want to try the [Safari plug-in to TinyMCE](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/safari); Safari also uses WebKit.  I gather also that [TinyMCE 3.x has better support for Safari/WebKit](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Compatiblity) than TinyMCE 2.x, so you might want to try upgrading to the latest 3.x version.

HTH

Alastair

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the TinyMCE to the latest, but it still fails.
The editor will display the first time you try to edit after login, but subsequent editing fails to bring up the TinyMCE editor

On the upside, Drupal 6.4 and the latest TinyMCE appear to work correctly, so I guess I'll need to update Drupal to v. 6 for this website.

edit
Refreshing the edit page renders TinyMCE in my current setup, so that's my answer for Drupal 5.7 in Chrome.